# AngularJS : How to avoid - Broadcast event called from app.js is triggered twice?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, angularjs

in app.js i'm using in callback function broadcast on the $rootScope to get fired method on the second controller.

```
function onSuccess(state) {
          if (state != true) {
          } else {
              $rootScope.$broadcast('proximityCatched', null);
          }
          //console.log('Proximity state: ' + (state ? 'near' : 'far'));
      };
```

On the controller i have listener:

```
$rootScope.$on('proximityCatched', function () {
            alert("TEST");
        });
```

Problem is that alert("TEST"); is triggered twice.

I tried to find any working solution using stopPropagation or using broadcasting on the normal scope, but without luck.

How can i do it please in the right way?

Thanks for any advice.

**Edit: Router config:**

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider
          .state('game', {
              url: "/game",
              templateUrl: "templates/game.html",
              controller: "GameCtrl"
          })
          .state('home', {
              url: "/home",
              templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
              controller: "HomeCtrl"
          })
        // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    });
```

Comment: are you attaching the controller twice in the route and the html ?

Comment: Do You think router that i just added into question? Controllers are mentioned here, in index.html and in ng-init

Comment: ok do you use `ng-controller` in html ?

Comment: Yes, should i remove it?

Comment: yes that's why its calling twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are attaching controller twice it will call twice.

check if you attaching controller in the `routes` configs and the html (by using `ng-controller`), if you attaching twice (using both ways) please remove one.

Comment: I thought, that controller must be defined in the index.html and if should be attached to any template (view) should be defined in the routes too. Removing the ng-controller attribute from the views solved my problem.

Comment: umm nope basically the controller assigned to a view and it will control the behaviors of that html content. if you have multiple views then then there should be multiple controllers to handle them, and you can define the controller in `route` config or in the views.

Comment: here is a good explanation about `ng-controller` http://blog.pluralsight.com/angularjs-step-by-step-controllers